# Packet size more than 1500

Tags: c#, .net, packet, sharppcap, packetdotnet

I'm trying to send more than 2000 bytes of data using SharpPcap and PacketDotNet.
But, the MTU (1500 bytes) is less than the size of the data.
I tried to set MTU (to 5000) using https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Changing-the-MTU-size-in-Windows-Vista-7-or-8, but still it is throwing error as follows :

```
SharpPcap.PcapException: Can't send packet: send error: PacketSendPacket failed
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDevice.SendPacket(Byte[] p, Int32 size)
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.PcapDevice.SendPacket(Byte[] p)
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.PcapDevice.SendPacket(Packet p)
```

Can anyone help me out here...

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things in order to send Ethernet packets larger than 1500 bytes in Windows:

- Change the MTU (you already got that covered)

```
    netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Your Interface Name" mtu=2000 store=persistent
```

- You need to activate Jumbo Frames in the Device Manager
  [image]

Note that this has to be done on both the device sending the packet, and the device receiving it.